# Como abrir un Form dentro de un panel que esta en el main form por medio de otro form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2019, visual

tengo un proyecto en visual studio que quiero abrir un Form dentro de un panel que esta en el Form principal por medio de un button en otro form

Este es mi codigo en el Form principal

```
 public void AbrirFormEnPanel2(object Formhijo)
        {
            if (this.MenuVertical2.Controls.Count > 0)
                this.MenuVertical2.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
            Form fh = Formhijo as Form;
            fh.TopLevel = false;
            fh.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            this.MenuVertical2.Controls.Add(fh);
            this.MenuVertical2.Tag = fh;
            fh.Show();
        }
```

Esto quiero poner en otro form para que se abra en el panel del form principal

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AbrirFormEnPanel2(new Franco());
        }
```

Aca me da un error que me dice que la variable "AbrirFormEnPanel2" no existe, igual la creo como en el form pricipal , y el nuevo error que aparece es que no existe el panel
Mi pregunta es , como hago que para poder utilizar el panel del form principal estando en otro form independiente

Comment: El error que le está saliendo  que "dice que la variable AbrirFormEnPanel2 no existe"   pienso que le esta saliendo porque esta la invocación al método AbrirFormEnPanel2 que la está realizando desde una clase (formulario) diferente a aquella en la cual implementó AbrirFormEnPanel2.

Answer (score 1):

Partamos de la base que no se ponen `Forms` dentro de `Panels` eso es incorrecto, para hacer eso existen los `User Control`

[Windows Forms: How to load User control dynamically in C#](https://foxlearn.com/articles/how-to-load-user-control-dynamically-in-csharp-69.html)

Si creas un user control

```
public class NombreUC : UserControl
{
   //codigo
}
```

Este es igual a un form solo que sin bordes

Entonces solo es cuestion de instanciarlo para ponerlo dentro de la coleccion de controls del panel

```
NombreUC uc = new NombreUC();
MenuVertical2.Controls.Add(uc);
```

Nota: no se que funcionalidad representa ese form hijo por eso le puse NombreUC, pero deberias cambiarlo por algo mas significativo para tu aplicacion

Para realizar acciones desde un `User Control` al `Form Principal` se usan eventos, al cual te adjuntas para realizar esas acciones.

Si desde el User Control que estara en el Panel quires realizar una accion en el form principal, expones un evento

```
public class NombreUC : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler AbrirUserControlEnPanel;

    public void button1_Click()
    {
        EventHandler handler = AbrirUserControlEnPanel;
        if (handler != null) 
            handler(this, e);
    }
}
```

Entonces desde el form principal te adjuntas al evento

```
public class FormPrincipal
{
    public void Form_Load(..){

        NombreUC uc = new NombreUC();
        uc.AbrirUserControlEnPanel += AbrirEnPanel;

        MenuVertical2.Controls.Add(uc);
    }

     public void AbrirEnPanel(EventArgs e)
     {
       //codigo
     }
}
```

[EventHandler Delegado](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.eventhandler?view=netframework-4.5.2)

[Simplificando las cosas con Events, EventHandlers & EventArgs](https://geeks.ms/eortuno/2013/07/20/simplificando-las-cosas-con-events-eventhandlers-eventargs/)

Comment: Exacto, los UserControl son perfectos, te permiten crear toda una vista con sus funcionalidades y serie de eventos asociados a los diferentes controles que la conforman. Además de su conveniente reutilización

Answer (score 0):

' NO NECESITAS UN PANEL, CHECA ESTO
' ASUMIENDO QUE ABRISTE UN PROYECTO NUEVO
' ANTES DE ABRIR EL CODIGO DEL FORM
' EN EL EXPLORADOR CAMBIA EL NOMBRE DE DISEÑO A TU FORMULARIO, DE Form1 A Form0
' Y ACEPTA QUE CAMBIE TODA LA REFERENCIA DEL PROYECTO CON ESE NOMBRE
' LUEGO AGREGA A TU Form0 QUE ES EL DE INICIO TRES BOTONES (Button1, Button2, Button3) Y OPCIONALMENTE UN Button4 PARA INVERTIR EL ARREGLO
' Y EN EL EXPLORADOR AGREGA TRES FORMULARIOS MAS A TU PROYECTO (Form1, Form2, Form3)
' FINALMENTE COPIA ESTE CODIGO EN TU Form0 TAL COMO SE VE ABAJO

Option Strict On

Public Class Form0

```
Public SOLO_UNO As Boolean = False       ' CAMBIANDO (SOLO_UNO = True) SE VERA SOLO UNO DE LOS TRES FORMULARIOS (CASO DEL Button4)
WithEvents FRM1 As New Form, FRM2 As New Form, FRM3 As New Form

Private Sub Form0_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Me.Text = ""
    Me.BackColor = Color.White
    Me.SizeGripStyle = SizeGripStyle.Show

    Me.Button1.Text = "Form1"
    Me.Button2.Text = "Form2"
    Me.Button3.Text = "Form3"

    INICIO()

End Sub

Private Sub INICIO()
    FRM1 = Form1
    FRMS(FRM1)

    FRM2 = Form2
    FRMS(FRM2)

    FRM3 = Form3
    FRMS(FRM3)
End Sub

Dim L As Integer = 25, T As Integer = 40, W As Integer = 650, H As Integer = 300 ' POSICION INICIAL (LEFT, TOP) Y DIMENSIONES (WIDTH, HEIGHT) DE CADA FORM

Private Sub FRMS(ByVal FRMX As Form)
    FRMX.TopLevel = False
    FRMX.ControlBox = False ' SI ESTA PROPIEDAD ES (False) NO HABRA BOTONES TRADICIONALES, Y TENDRAS QUE PONER LOS PROPIOS COMO SE MUESTRA AL FINAL
    FRMX.Text = ""
    FRMX.Location = New Point(L, T)
    FRMX.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro

    If SOLO_UNO = False Then
        FRMX.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable
        FRMX.SizeGripStyle = SizeGripStyle.Show
        FRMX.Size = New Size(W, H)
    Else
        FRMX.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
        FRMX.SizeGripStyle = SizeGripStyle.Hide
        FRMX.Size = New Size(Me.Width - 65, Me.Height - 115)
        FRMX.Anchor = CType((AnchorStyles.Left + AnchorStyles.Top + AnchorStyles.Right + AnchorStyles.Bottom), AnchorStyles)
    End If

    Controls.Add(FRMX)
End Sub

' AQUI SE MUESTRA COMO ABRIR CADA FORMULARIO CON EL PROCESO BUTTONS ABAJO MENCIONADO 

Dim FRM As New Form

Private Sub BUTTONS_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles _
    Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click, Button4.Click

    Dim CTRL As Control = CType(sender, Control)

    Select Case CTRL.Name
        Case Button1.Name
            FRM = FRM1 : FRM.Show() : FRM.BringToFront()

        Case Button2.Name
            FRM = FRM2 : FRM.Show() : FRM.BringToFront()

        Case Button3.Name
            FRM = FRM3 : FRM.Show() : FRM.BringToFront()
```

' Y SI DURANTE EL TIEMPO DE EJECUCION QUIERES INVERTIR EL ARREGLO

```
        Case Button4.Name
            FRM1.Close()
            FRM2.Close()
            FRM3.Close()

            If SOLO_UNO = False Then
                SOLO_UNO = True
            Else
                SOLO_UNO = False
            End If

            INICIO()
    End Select

End Sub

' MOVIMIENTO DEL Form0

Declare Auto Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer
Declare Auto Function ReleaseCapture Lib "user32.dll" () As Boolean

Private Sub Form_MouseDown_1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles _
    Me.MouseDown, FRM1.MouseDown, FRM2.MouseDown, FRM3.MouseDown

    If SOLO_UNO = True Then
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
            Const WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN As Integer = &HA1
            Const HT_CAPTION As Integer = &H2
            ReleaseCapture()
            SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form_MouseDown_2(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles _
    Me.MouseDown

    If SOLO_UNO = False Then
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
            Const WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN As Integer = &HA1
            Const HT_CAPTION As Integer = &H2
            ReleaseCapture()
            SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

' AQUI UNA CONFIRMACION PARA EL CIERRE DE ESTE FORM QUE ES EL PRINCIPAL

Private Sub Form0_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Dim RESP As Integer = MsgBox("Confirme Salir del Programa", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)

    If RESP = vbYes Then

    Else
        e.Cancel = True
    End If

End Sub
```

End Class

'' Y PARA TERMINAR, AGREGA ESTOS PROCEDIMIENTOS AL CODIGO DE TUS OTROS FORMULARIOS (Form1, Form2, Form3)

```
'WithEvents LBL As New Label

'Private Sub Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
'    If Form0.SOLO_UNO = False Then
'        Controls.Add(LBL)
'        LBL.Font = New Font("Consolas", 11.5, FontStyle.Regular) : LBL.BackColor = Me.BackColor : LBL.ForeColor = Color.DimGray
'        LBL.AutoSize = True : LBL.Text = " X "
'        LBL.Location = New Point(CInt(Me.Width - LBL.Width * 1.45), 0)
'        LBL.Anchor = CType(AnchorStyles.Right + AnchorStyles.Top, AnchorStyles)
'        LBL.Visible = True
'    End If

'    For Each CTRL1 As Control In Me.Controls
'        AddHandler CTRL1.MouseClick, AddressOf Form_BringToFront

'        For Each CTRL2 As Control In CTRL1.Controls
'            AddHandler CTRL2.MouseClick, AddressOf Form_BringToFront

'            For Each CTRL3 As Control In CTRL2.Controls
'                AddHandler CTRL3.MouseClick, AddressOf Form_BringToFront
'            Next
'        Next
'    Next

'End Sub

'Private Sub Form_BringToFront()
'    Me.BringToFront()
'End Sub

'Private Sub LBL_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles LBL.MouseMove
'    LBL.BackColor = Color.Red : LBL.ForeColor = Color.White
'    LBL.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
'    Application.DoEvents()
'    Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
'    LBL.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
'    LBL.BackColor = Me.BackColor : LBL.ForeColor = Color.DimGray
'End Sub

'Private Sub LBL_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles LBL.MouseDown
'    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
'        Me.Visible = False
'        Application.DoEvents()
'    End If
'End Sub

'Dim Xobj As Single, Yobj As Single
'Dim Xfrm As Single, Yfrm As Single
'Dim TM As Boolean = False
'Dim SNR As Control

'Sub Mueve_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDown
'    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
'        SNR = CType(sender, Control)
'        SNR.BringToFront()

'        Xobj = e.X
'        Yobj = e.Y

'        TM = True

'        Application.DoEvents()
'    End If
'End Sub

'Sub Mueve_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
'    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
'        If TM = True Then
'            SNR = CType(sender, Control)

'            Xfrm = e.X + SNR.Left
'            Yfrm = e.Y + SNR.Top

'            SNR.Left = CInt(Xfrm - Xobj)
'            SNR.Top = CInt(Yfrm - Yobj)

'            Application.DoEvents()
'        End If
'    End If
'End Sub

'Sub Mueve_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseUp
'    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
'        TM = False
'        Application.DoEvents()
'    End If
'End Sub
```

Comment: Considera que internet, mayúsculas = GRITAR. Por cierto, haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.